# Convert Java UDP receiver to Python

Tags: java, python-3.5

I can receive the data of an UDP stream ([live view of a Panasonic camera](http://www.personal-view.com/talks/discussion/6703/control-your-gh3-from-a-web-browser-now-with-video-/p1)) using this Java code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class UDPReceiver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final int serverPort = 49199;
        final InetAddress myip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.1.1");
        final DatagramSocket theSocket = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);
        final byte[] inBuffer = new byte[30000];
        final DatagramPacket theRecievedPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuffer, inBuffer.length, myip, serverPort);
        theSocket.receive(theRecievedPacket);
        final byte[] outBuffer = theRecievedPacket.getData();
        System.out.println(theRecievedPacket.getLength()); // e.g. 13749
        theSocket.close();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite this code in Python:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("127.0.1.1", 49199))
data = sock.recv(30000)
print("received data: ", data)
```

but `sock.recv` never returns. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** The following Node.js receiver does not receive data eiter:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
  server.close();
});

server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

server.on('listening', () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});

server.bind({
  address: '127.0.1.1',
  port: 49199,
  exclusive: true
});
```

Comment: Is there any data sent to `127.0.1.1:49199`?

Comment: Yes, `theRecievedPacket.getLength()` (in the Java program) returns a value greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Python and Node.js both work with IP address `0.0.0.0`